# Closed a question after 8 years and 4 months

Tags: support, specific-question, vote-to-close, closed-questions

I asked this question 8 years and 4 months ago.
[When should I create a new DbContext()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551100/when-should-i-create-a-new-dbcontext)

Today I got a notification that it has been closed and was linked to another thread with fewer and less detailed answers.

What is the reason for this, I can't see this filling any purpose after all this time?

Comment: At a guess, the user meant to close the other question as a duplicate of yours. In truth, only the gold badger can tell you why.

Comment: Because a new answer was posted on it 11 hours ago, thus drawing attention to it. it was closed as a duplicate of an even older question, surprisingly

Comment: A question being older doesn’t make it impervious to votes of any kind. The owner also gets reputation from upvotes, for example.

Comment: As an FYI, you can @notify a user who has cast a binding single closure vote. See [this Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for details.

Comment: Generally closure is fine, however in this case I do not understand why it was closed

Comment: Woof, 4 questions in one. Questions have been closed as too broad / not focused for less (even back in 2012). I'm kind of amazed it took this long and it ends up being a duplicate closure.

Comment: I would have appreciated having been asked directly by pinging me instead of escalating the matter right away. I was lucky someone had the sense to notify me of this question.

Comment: @Gimby Sub-questions #1, #2 and #3 are closely connected to each other. Sub-question #4 pushes the envelope a bit, but it could be reframed as part of the OP's overarching goal of figuring out whether the approach proposed in the question is sensible. All in all, I don't feel it is necessary to close the question.

Comment: @JensB I have edited the final part of your question to remove the list of four sub-questions, which, to my eyes, made it look broader than it actually is.

Comment: @duplode I never said that I would have closed it myself, I only say that my mind is blown that nobody else did.

Comment: I would like the commend the way the subquestions were not exactly edited out but were simply rephrased so they don't look like a red herring, all existing answers that quote the original state of the question were not lowered in value this way. Bonus points for that.